# setInterval weird behavior in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I want to run a function once every second, and the function itself takes 3 seconds to execute. the results are that each interval is executed at a difference of `<function execution time>*2+<setInterval delay>`

I wrote the following sample code:

```
var seconds = 3;

setInterval(
    function(){
            console.info(new Date().toString());
            var waitTill = new Date(new Date().getTime() + seconds * 1000);
            while(waitTill > new Date()){}
    },1000
);
```

and each iteration is as I stated in the formula:

```
Wed Jul 13 2016 09:49:07 GMT+0300 (IDT)
Wed Jul 13 2016 09:49:14 GMT+0300 (IDT)
Wed Jul 13 2016 09:49:21 GMT+0300 (IDT)
Wed Jul 13 2016 09:49:28 GMT+0300 (IDT)
```

the documentation doesn't state this behaviour. the results that I thought that will be is that each iteration will execute after 1 second no matter how much time the execution of the interval function takes.

what's going on?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

using Nodejs 6.3.0

## update

tried this code on the browser... google chrome... here the interval executes every 3 seconds, which is still weird.

## update

thanks for all of your comments, one last thing that's not clear.
why in NodeJS, when I have `setInterval()` set to 1 second, and the function execution takes 3 seconds, why the next execution is 7 seconds instead of 4 seconds or even 3 seconds. that seems really strange behaviour for me. is that an acceptable behaviour ?

Comment: @Andreas: NodeJS is single-threaded; JavaScript is *not*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the documentation doesn't state this behavior

NodeJS's [documentation for `setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg) characteristically states virtually nothing about its behavior, other than that it will repeat the task.

> the results that I thought that will be is that each iteration will execute after 1 second no matter how much time the execution of the interval function takes

If you mean you could have overlapping executions, you can't in NodeJS; it runs your code on a single thread.

If you mean you expected each iteration to run a second after the last completed, that's not how `setInterval` traditionally works. `setInterval` has traditionally had at least two different behaviors depending on which implementation you were using: Scheduling the next iteration at the *beginning* of the current one, or scheduling it at the *end* of the current one. And that's just on browsers. It's since [been standardized for browsers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timer-initialization-steps), but NodeJS isn't a browser and isn't required to work the same way. (And in fact, it doesn't in another way as well: On browsers, `setInterval` is required to return a number; on NodeJS, it returns an object.) Remember that timers are not a feature of JavaScript, they're a feature of the host environment.

Instead, to get it to run again a second (roughly) after it finished previously, use `setTimeout` at the end of the function to schedule the next one to run a second later.

Re your edit:

> why in NodeJS, when I have setInterval() set to 1 second, and the function execution takes 3 seconds, why the next execution is 7 seconds instead of 4 seconds or even 3 seconds. that seems really strange behavior for me. is that an acceptable behavior ?

Yes. It's strange and surprising (in my view), but NodeJS determines its own behavior for `setInterval`, so it's *acceptable*. In my experiments (below), it appears to measure how long the previous execution of your function took, then **add** that to the timer length so that it's `lastExecutionLength + desiredInterval` before it fires it again. That's markedly at variance with the spec for browsers, but again, NodeJS isn't a browser.

Here's my test script:

```
let counter = 0;
let timeAtEndOfLastExecution = 0;
let timer = null;

function log(msg) {
    console.log(Date.now() + ": " + msg);
}

function tick() {
    let start = Date.now();
    if (timeAtEndOfLastExecution) {
        log("tick (" + (Date.now() - timeAtEndOfLastExecution) + "ms)");
    } else {
        log("tick");
    }
    if (++counter == 10) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
        let wait = 200 + (Math.floor(8 * Math.random()) * 100);
        log("waiting " + wait + "ms");
        let stopWaiting = Date.now() + wait;
        while (Date.now() < stopWaiting) {
            // busy wait
        }
        log("exiting callback after " + (Date.now() - start) + "ms");
        timeAtEndOfLastExecution = Date.now();
    }
}
timer = setInterval(tick, 200);
```

And a sample run (with Node v6.2.2):

```
1468396730618: tick
1468396730619: waiting 400ms
1468396731020: exiting callback after 416ms
1468396731637: tick (617ms)
1468396731637: waiting 500ms
1468396732137: exiting callback after 500ms
1468396732837: tick (700ms)
1468396732837: waiting 900ms
1468396733737: exiting callback after 900ms
1468396734837: tick (1100ms)
1468396734837: waiting 300ms
1468396735137: exiting callback after 300ms
1468396735637: tick (500ms)
1468396735637: waiting 700ms
1468396736337: exiting callback after 700ms
1468396737237: tick (900ms)
1468396737237: waiting 800ms
1468396738037: exiting callback after 800ms
1468396739036: tick (999ms)
1468396739036: waiting 900ms
1468396739936: exiting callback after 900ms
1468396741036: tick (1100ms)
1468396741036: waiting 700ms
1468396741736: exiting callback after 700ms
1468396742636: tick (900ms)
1468396742636: waiting 200ms
1468396742836: exiting callback after 200ms
1468396743236: tick (400ms)
```

As we can see, it's consistently waiting the length of the previous iteration plus the interval I gave:

- First callback took a total of 416ms; the next started 617ms after it returned
- Second callback took 500ms; the next started 700ms after it returned
- Third callback 900ms; the next started 1100ms after it returned

Comment: why I get different results between nodejs and the browser ? and why does nodejs waits the execution time again, and then the delay and only then executes the next iteration ?

Comment: @ufk: NodeJS and browsers are different environments; remember that `setInterval` isn't a part of JavaScript, it's a feature of the environment in which your code is running. The exact way that `setInterval` works is (now) [specified for browsers](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timer-initialization-steps), but NodeJS isn't required to work the same way.

Comment: ok.. thanks for everything. just one thing is not clear to me. updating main post

Comment: @ufk: That's some weird behavior (which I can replicate; see above), but NodeJS gets to set its own rules.